# Spring Security LDAP: error code 49 - cannot bind the principalDn

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I am using Spring security ldap 3.2.6  and able to authenticate successfully  for some user but it fails for some with following error

```
2016-03-22_10:25:45.338 DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.a.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider - authenticate - Processing authentication request for user: 170100@mydomain.net
2016-03-22_10:25:45.382 DEBUG o.s.s.l.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate - searchForSingleEntryInternal - Searching for entry under DN '', base = 'dc=mydomain,dc=net', filter = '(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0}))'
2016-03-22_10:25:45.383 INFO  o.s.s.l.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate - searchForSingleEntryInternal - Ignoring PartialResultException
2016-03-22_10:25:45.384 DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.LdapAuthenticationProvider - authenticate - Processing authentication request for user: 170100@mydomain.net
2016-03-22_10:25:45.387 DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator - bindWithDn - Attempting to bind as cn=170100@mydomain.net,cn=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=net,dc=springframework,dc=org
2016-03-22_10:25:45.388 DEBUG o.s.s.l.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource - setupEnvironment - Removing pooling flag for user cn=170100@mydomain.net,cn=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=net,dc=springframework,dc=org
2016-03-22_10:25:45.538 DEBUG o.s.s.l.a.BindAuthenticator - handleBindException - Failed to bind as cn=170100@mydomain.net,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=net: org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - cannot bind the principalDn.]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - cannot bind the principalDn.]
2016-03-22_10:25:45.545 DEBUG o.h.g.u.AuthenticationFailureListener - onApplicationEvent - Updating Failed Login count for {} 
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
       at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator.authenticate(BindAuthenticator.java:95) ~[spring-security-ldap-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:178) ~[spring-security-ldap-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:80) ~[spring-security-ldap-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156) [spring-security-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177) [spring-security-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:90) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_73]
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_73]
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_73]
```

security Java  configuration

```
  @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
        auth.eraseCredentials(false);
        auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("cn={0},CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=net");
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(env.getProperty("mydomain.net"),
                env.getProperty("ldap://mydir01.mydomain.net:389/"));
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper);
        return provider;
    }
```

I pass the full name like 2000791@mydomain.net and it works for some users and not for others. 
LDAP Admin says the account is stable, active and not locked.
So what could be the problem.

Comment: Is 2000791@mydomain.net the correct CN of the user?

Comment: The exception says "Bad credentials". Is the password correct?

Comment: Yes the CN is correct and the password also. I am able to login into another system using the same ID & Password. I guess it might have something to do with Active Directory. but not sure

Comment: I solved this issue by adding aes-crypto dependence in the pom file.I recommend adding encryption dependence as per your company standards to solve this issue.